# How to remove unnecessary line breaks in SQL Plus Spooling?

Tags: sql, database, command-line, sqlplus, spool

I am spooling a package from a database and this is what I get:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY "CPI"."GIPI_WBOND_BASIC_PKG"                   
    AS                                                                              
       FUNCTION get_gipi_wbond_basic (p_par_id gipi_wbond_basic.par_id%TYPE)        
          RETURN gipi_wbond_basic_tab PIPELINED                                     
       IS                                                                           
          v_wbond   gipi_wbond_basic_type;                                          
       BEGIN                                                                        
          FOR i IN (SELECT a.par_id,        a.obligee_no,    a.bond_dtl,      a.inde
    mnity_text,                                                                     
                           a.clause_type,   a.waiver_limit,  a.contract_date, a.cont
    ract_dtl,                                                                       
                           a.prin_id,       a.co_prin_sw,    a.np_no,         a.coll
    _flag,                                                                          
                           a.plaintiff_dtl, a.defendant_dtl, a.civil_case_no        
                      FROM gipi_wbond_basic a                                       
                     WHERE a.par_id = p_par_id)
```

And I am expecting it to be something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY cpi.gipi_wbond_basic_pkg
AS
   FUNCTION get_gipi_wbond_basic (p_par_id gipi_wbond_basic.par_id%TYPE)
      RETURN gipi_wbond_basic_tab PIPELINED
   IS
      v_wbond   gipi_wbond_basic_type;
   BEGIN
      FOR i IN (SELECT a.par_id, a.obligee_no, a.bond_dtl, a.indemnity_text,
                       a.clause_type, a.waiver_limit, a.contract_date,
                       a.contract_dtl, a.prin_id, a.co_prin_sw, a.np_no,
                       a.coll_flag, a.plaintiff_dtl, a.defendant_dtl,
                       a.civil_case_no
                  FROM gipi_wbond_basic a
                 WHERE a.par_id = p_par_id)
```

Please help me on how can I get rid of those new lines and ugly format. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I am using SQL Plus direct from MS Windows Command Prompt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok this one solved my problem.

From this,

```
SET HEADING OFF;
SET ECHO OFF;
SET PAGES 999;
SET LONG 999999;
```

I added this:

```
SET LONGCHUNKSIZE 999999;
SET PAGESIZE 0;
SET LINESIZE 500;
```

Comment: Thank you. We have lost days on this issue. This is the first "solution" that works for us

Comment: Note that setting the linesize to a very high value does not work. I found out 32000 works, 50000 not (sqlplus 19.16.0.0.0)

Answer (score 1):

TO remove extra Line breaks Try :-
**SET FEED OFF**

Answer (score 0):

Additionally (to ladiesman1792's own answers, which were *below* this post when I posted!):

```
column text format a120 --<< will wrap at 120 chars (maybe bytes, not sure on that)
```

This is an Oracle sqlplus directive, as per the other answers.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using the regular expression in SSMS:

1) Ctrl-H to bring up the Find And Replace window
2) Select USE -> Regular Expressions
3) Put ^\n in the Find What
4) Keep Replace With empty
5) Click Replace (All)

Good luck
-- Nilesh Umaretiya (India)