# How to spool separate queries to same file without a page break?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, page-break

I am trying to run multiple separate queries in one script using SQL*Plus and spool the output to a file. It is currently spooling out, but it is inserting a page break between all queries, and I only want a page break between specific ones.

What I am doing:

```
SPOOL directory/QUERY_OUTPUT_FILE

SELECT .... FROM QUERY1
/
-- No page break desired here, but getting one anyway

SELECT .... FROM QUERY2
/
-- Page break desired here

SELECT .... FROM QUERY3
/

SPOOL OFF
```

How can I control whether a page break is inserted or not between these queries?

Comment: See here maybe?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601251/how-to-remove-unnecessary-line-breaks-in-sql-plus-spooling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you're currently setting [`newpage`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG091) to zero, either in your script or in a local or global login script.

> Sets the number of blank lines to be printed from the top of each page to the top title. A value of zero places a formfeed at the beginning of each page (including the first page) and clears the screen on most terminals. If you set NEWPAGE to NONE, SQL*Plus does not print a blank line or formfeed between the report pages.

You can use that setting to control when you see a page break; set it to a non-zero value to have blank lines between the first two, then switch it back to zero to get line breaks back

For example:

```
SET pages 1000
SET feedback OFF

SPOOL spool_test

SET newpage NONE

SELECT * FROM DUAL
connect by level < 5
/

SET newpage 3

SELECT * FROM DUAL
connect by level < 5
/

SET newpage 0

SELECT * FROM DUAL
connect by level < 5
/

SPOOL OFF
```

The `spool_test.lst` file that created looks like this:

```
D
-
X
X
X
X



D
-
X
X
X
X
^LD
-
X
X
X
X
```

At the start of the file there is nothing before the query output starts, because of the initial `NONE` setting. Between the first two query outputs there are three blank lines, from the second call to `set newpage`. Between the second and third there is just a `^L`, which is a page break (and form feed) character - ASCII 12.